# Compute a 4 4 matrix M such that MA is the row-reduced echelon form of A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Compute a 4 X 4 matrix M such that MA is the row-reduced echelon form of
A. (Hint: M can be written as a product of elementary matrices.)

A:= \begin{pmatrix}3&2&5&-1&-4\\2&1&4&2&-4\\1&-3&9&-2&15\\4&2&8&1&-5\end{pmatrix}

I've worked out the rref of A to be

\begin{pmatrix}1&0&3&0&1\\0&1&-2&0&-4\\0&0&0&1&-1\\0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}

I did this by using row operations, first of all I swapped rows 1 and 3, then I used row operations to eliminate the first column, then divided the second row by 2/7, then eliminated then second column, then divided the the 3rd row by -31/7, then eliminated the fourth column

but how do I use this to work out M?

Comment: That depends on what you did to get to that RREF.

Comment: How did you get that RREF?

Comment: I used row operations, first of all I swapped rows 1 and 3, then I used row operations to eliminate the first column, then divided the second row by 2/7, then eliminated then second column, then divided the the 3rd row by -31/7, then eliminated the fourth column

Comment: Now that that information is available the question is answerable. Please add the above to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do the exact same sequence of row operations on the $4 \times 4$ identity:
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1} \to 
\pmatrix{
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&1} \to 
\pmatrix{
0&0&1&0\\
0&1&-2&0\\
1&0&-3&0\\
0&0&-4&1} \to \cdots
$$
eventually, you'll end up with such a matrix $M$. An equivalent way to go about this is to row reduce the augmented matrix $(A \mid I_{4 \times 4})$.  When this matrix is row reduced, you'll end up with the rref form of $A$ on the left, and the desired $M$ on the right.

See [this link (Wolfram Alpha)](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B3%2C2%2C5%2C-1%2C-4%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2C4%2C2%2C-4%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C-3%2C9%2C-2%2C15%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B4%2C2%2C8%2C1%2C-5%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D) for one solution. to the problem (by the latter method).